# Dimensionality not matching for differential of matrix with orthogonality constraints

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, matrix-calculus, orthogonality

I was reading through the following answer out of curiosity about calculating the differential of a matrix with [orthogonality constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3806468/580635). Briefly the mathematics works out as follows:

$
\text{Let } X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, \text{ so that } X^TX=I_{n\times n}, \text{ } m > n
$

$ 
\text{Then }, d(X^TX)= dX^T X + X^T dX = 0
$

I originally saw no problem with that except then I noticed that: $dX^T X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$  *and*  $dX X^T\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$.

If these two matrices have different dimensions ... how is the addition over the matrices even defined? Or how should one interpret this at all?

Comment: There is no $dX X^T$ involved, only $dX^T X$ and $X^T dX$.
Matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: oh! it must have been a silly transcription on my part. I've just been looking at too many symbols today it seems ..

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$dX\in \R^{m\times n}$, and it will be clearer if you use brackets:
$$d(X^TX) = (dX)^TX + X^T(dX) = 0,$$
both terms are in $R^{n\times n}$. Equivalently, if $\Delta_X$ is tangent to the Stiefel manifold at $X$, differentiate the relation $X^TX=I$ in direction $\Delta_X$ shows $(\Delta_X)^TX + X^T(\Delta_X) = 0$, or $X^T\Delta_X$ is antisymmetric.

Comment: Thank you the bracketing idea is actually quite helpful.